# Is there a way to programmatically call a checkbox and a column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, excel, checkbox, datagridview

I am making an Excel Validation Program. Once imported, each columns would be validated if they are decimals.

[image]

The checkboxes are made dynamically and represents the columns in a datatable per tabs (tabs are sheets from an Excel File) using this code:

```
int dynamicHeight = 0;
int padding = 10;

CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i ++)
{


    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].Name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    dynamicHeight += 20;
    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
    //panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);
}
```

I want to call them but ***dynamically*** too. What I am doing is ***manually*** presetting every checkbox like this:

```
chk[0].CheckedChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    decimal num;
    if (chk[0].Checked == true && chk[0].Name.Contains(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("HELLOW WORLD " + 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["January"].Value.ToString(), out num))
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dt.Columns["January"].ColumnName].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dt.Columns["January"].ColumnName].Value.ToString() == "")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["January"].Value.ToString() + "  NOT A DECIMAL!");
                }

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a fix or solution for this so that I don't have to preset them all manually? Cause what if an excel file has a different column name that would mean presetting new columns again.

Comment: What do you mean preset each checkbox? You mean with a specific method for when it becomes checked?

Comment: Also you can refactor: `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dt.Columns["January"].ColumnName].Value.ToString() {}`

Comment: Yes. If there's a way without inputting them in a specific method when a checkbox gets checks.


Basically want I want is like this. If checkbox _January_ is checked, then the column January from the `DataTable` would be validated if there are non-decimal values without having to call a specific method calling them by index value or column names.

Comment: Comparing the checkbox name to the column name would probably accomplish that task

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Can you explain? I'm fairly new in C#.

Comment: instead of doing `chk[0].CheckChanged` do `[chk[i].CheckChanged` and add it in your `for` statement. Change the cell name checks where it says "January" to `chk[i].Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i ++)
{
    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].Name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    dynamicHeight += 20;
    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
    //panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);

    chk[i].CheckedChanged += (s, ev) =>
    {
        decimal num;
        if (chk[i].Checked == true && chk[i].Name.Contains(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName))
        {
        //MessageBox.Show("HELLOW WORLD " + 0);

          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
              if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[chk[i].Name].Value.ToString(), out num))
                {
                  if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dt.Columns[chk[i].Name].ColumnName].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dt.Columns[chk[i].Name].ColumnName].Value.ToString() == "")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[chk[i].Name].Value.ToString() + "  NOT A DECIMAL!");
                    }

                 }
                 else
                 {

                  }
             }
         }
    };

}
```

This is not tested or anything, but it's a basic idea of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I tried using code but in a line it says in `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)`  it says it cannot be declared because it would give a different meaning to `i` which already exists in the scope...

Comment: The 2nd for loop inside the `CheckedChanged` event handler is the issue. Just change i to another variable name like `k`. So `for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.RowCount; k++)` etc

Comment: Hi, I've changed it all to `k`, but there are still errors, mind if you update the code for me to visualize what you're trying to say? https://imgur.com/a/ix60m

Comment: What's the total number of columns? The index should not go out of range because it's specified by `db.Columns.Count - 1` -- I'm honestly not too sure what it is without further investigation

Comment: 19 is the total column. I don't why this problem is occurring. :/

Comment: 19 is the total columns then it would be out of range. Index would end at 18 because arrays start at 0 in C#. Change it to `dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165102/discussion-between-shan-coralde-and-tom-farley).